# React Native - secureTextEntry Disable IOS 13+ Strong Password behavior

Tags: ios, react-native

I have an create account form in my app and now on iOS devices running 13+ I'm having an issue where if the the user presses the "done" key while entering a password the normal secure password dots are replaced with the following (see below). How to disable this behavior so it continues to work as it did on older devices?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not a optimal solution, but adding blurOnSubmit, and a keyboard Dismiss on submit seems to get the desired behavior back:

```
import { Keyboard } from 'react-native'

<TextInput
   ...
   blurOnSubmit={false}
   onSubmitEditing={()=> Keyboard.dismiss()}
/>
```

Comment: As of iOS 15.4 this does not seem to run, is there a better way to do this in 2022 - https://snack.expo.dev/@ramakay/spunky-celery

Answer (score 24):

Try the following prop:

`textContentType={'oneTimeCode'}`

Answer (score 5):

This problem occurs only if I use two `TextInput` components with `secureTextEntry` set to `true`.

If you don't need that, you might want to get rid of the second `TextInput` component.

You can also hack around with the value of `secureTextEntry`, e.g. setting it only to `true` when `onFocus` event was triggered and evolve it from there.
(see: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27586#issuecomment-580739397)

Comment: Tried everything and I'm using onSubmitEditing to focus the next field so that wasnt viable, hacking secureTextEntry was the only thing that worked. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, adding `textContentType="oneTimeCode"` to all TextInput on the screen helped solved the issue.

Comment: Security risk and also breaks other functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `textContentType` prop

`textContentType="none"` If you want to disable all the autofill feature.

Quote from RN 0.64 docs

> Give the keyboard and the system information about the expected
> semantic meaning for the content that users enter.
>
> For iOS 11+ you can set textContentType to username or password to
> enable autofill of login details from the device keychain.
>
> For iOS 12+ newPassword can be used to indicate a new password input
> the user may want to save in the keychain, and oneTimeCode can be used
> to indicate that a field can be autofilled by a code arriving in an
> SMS.
>
> To disable autofill, set textContentType to none.

You should use the prop properly or else it will cause improper behaviours on users device.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#textcontenttype

Answer (score 1):

The best solution so far is to disable the simulator strong password feature.

Go to:

1. Settings
2. Passwords
3. It will ask for a password! Type anything and tap on Done.
4. Turn On `AutoFill Passwords` and turn it Off again.

Source: [Strong password autofill appears in iOS simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55378639/3632172)

Comment: this would only fix it on your device... it's still going to happen when people use your app

Answer (score 1):

Despite all the hacks and fixes I've seen this is the only one the fully fixed the problem.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21911#issuecomment-833144889

```
<TextInput secureTextEntry={true}/> // input1
<TextInput style={{height: 0.1}}/> // a dummy that jammed in between two secure texts
<TextInput secureTextEntry={true}/> // input2
```

Answer (score -1):

just add

```
autoCorrect={false}
```

solved for me